# Find the value of $\sqrt[5]{0.00000165}$ given $\log165=2.2174839$ and $\log697424=5.8434968$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

> Find the value of $\sqrt[5]{0.00000165}$ given $\log165=2.2174839$ and $\log697424=5.8434968$

$\log x=\log\sqrt[5]{0.00000165}$

$\Rightarrow \log x =\dfrac{1}{5}\log0.00000165=\dfrac{1}{5}(\overline{6}.2174839$)

$\Rightarrow \dfrac{1}{5}(\overline{10}+4.2174839) = \overline{2}.8434968$

I don't understand how $\overline{2}.8434968$ came about. I can see the $\overline{2}$ came from $\dfrac{1}{5}\times\overline{10}$, but then where did the rest come from? I'm pretty sure this problem isn't asking me to use a calculator and plug in $\dfrac{1}{5} \times 4.2174839$. There's a trick I'm missing here. Thanks.

Comment: What does the overline mean?  E.g. $\overline{10}$?

Comment: @NickPeterson I think in these (old fashioned) logarithm sums one writes $\overline{10}\cdot 77$ to mean $(-10)+0\cdot 77$.

Comment: Do you know that $\frac x 5 = \frac {2x}{10}$? No need for a calculator to compute $\frac {4.2174839\times 2}{10}=\frac {8.4349678}{10} = .84349678$

Comment: I once had a student ask for a calculator to divide $60$ by $12$. But this is an easy division by $5$, or, as @SergeBallesta says, multiplication by $2$ followed by a decimal shift.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $\log 165 = 2.2174839$ is given, it means, the base is $10$.
So we have
$$
\log(0.00000165^{\frac{1}{5}})
=
\frac{1}{5}\cdot \log(0.00000165)
=
\frac{1}{5}\cdot \log(\frac{165}{10^8}) \\
=
\frac{1}{5}\cdot (\log(165) - \log(10^8))
=
\frac{1}{5}\cdot (\underbrace{\log(165)}_{\text{given}} - 8\cdot\underbrace{\log(10)}_{=1}).
$$

Comment: Nice *underbraces*.